# How to open a webpage on windows logon?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to run a webpage when a user logs onto their user account.. . in my C# App..

```
string startup = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
```

Comment: So, what is the problem ? Can you elaborate a bit ??

Comment: @ChristianDietz there's no problem I wana goto www.google.ca when a user Log's into windows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may **create a batch file and schedule it to run every time when user logs in**.

The batch file will have only one line.

```
start <url>
```

e.g.

```
start http://www.google.ca
```

> This script would open the <url> in **user's default web browser**.

Comment: theghostofc : So I just make the .bat file and put it in start up folder?

Comment: @user2309648, you may **schedule it as a task and make it to run every time a user logs in** - this is what you intended to do, right? Please remember to **take proper security measures so that this batch file is not mis-used by any malware or virus to compromise your system**.

Comment: what do i do? Hide the file?

Comment: @user2309648, hide the file, store it in a system folder, make it read-only. That should suffice. Other authors may suggest more options.

Comment: @user2309648 please mark the answer which helped you to help our fellow developers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateUrlShortcut(string linkName, string linkUrl)
{
    string dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dir + "\\" + linkName + ".url"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine("URL=" + linkUrl);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Cal the above funaction as follows:

```
CreateUrlShortcut("google link", "http://www.google.ca/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood everything. But here's an example of code that opens (*. Html) web page stored in your application once the user logged.

```
bool isLoged = //...
//Get the absolute path of the application
DirectoryInfo myPathWork = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
//if the use is loged
if(isLoged)
{
   //Open web page stored in the directory of the application with the default web browser.
   Process.Start(myPathWork.FullName+"myWebPage.html");
}
```